# Python - Pandas Multi Index Pivot - Fill All Rows with data (no empty or merged cells)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot

I am having issue with formatting a dataframe that has been pivot'd with pandas.

If somebody could point me in the right direction to change the way a pandas pivot formats a data frame that would be amazing. I am currently using the following formula for the pivot table creation:

```
tempTable = pd.pivot_table(newArr, values=['TotalTime', 'AvailTime'], margins = True, index=['UserID','Workgroup','Date'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Which produces the correct data, but in the incorrect format..

So I need to change it from this format:

| UserID | Workgroup | Date | AvailTime | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Customer Service | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 10000 |
|  |  | 2021-08-30 | 12000 | 15000 |
|  | Service Delivery | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 90000 |
|  |  | 2021-08-30 | 7000 | 12000 |
| Allen | Customer Service | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 10000 |
|  |  | 2021-08-30 | 12000 | 15000 |
|  | Service Delivery | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 90000 |
|  |  | 2021-08-30 | 7000 | 12000 |

To this format:

| UserID | Workgroup | Date | AvailTime | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Customer Service | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 10000 |
| James | Customer Service | 2021-08-30 | 12000 | 15000 |
| James | Service Delivery | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 90000 |
| James | Service Delivery | 2021-08-30 | 7000 | 12000 |
| Allen | Customer Service | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 10000 |
| Allen | Customer Service | 2021-08-30 | 12000 | 15000 |
| Allen | Service Delivery | 2021-08-29 | 9000 | 90000 |
| Allen | Service Delivery | 2021-08-30 | 7000 | 12000 |

Long story short, I need the data stored in that format to get excel to interact with it correctly for xlookups etc (as from a best practice standpoint, you should not be storing information in merged cells when calculating in excel).

Comment: Not sure if the tables formatted correctly. It showed them looking fine before I posted it, and when I go to edit it, it shows its fine. But viewing on this page for me it looks like it didn't format correctly at all.

Comment: maybe a reset_index at the end of your code?

Comment: I'll give that a go quickly. @sammywemmy 
Also, are you able to see the tables correctly on this webpage? I can't tell if its my browser or the way I formatted the tables when posting this.

Comment: no worries. it seems an extra line between the table and the preceding sentence was what was needed

Comment: @sammywemmy [This](https://janakiev.com/blog/pandas-multiindex-pivot/) indicates that you are probably right with your first suggestion. I am going to run the data again and post back with results. I will feel a bit silly if that was all I was missing.

Comment: im not sure if this is an answer but why dont you do like this? `df.fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: @sanzo213 That looks like it could be a good solution. I am trying out about 4 different solutions, and will post back the results from each.
Unfortunately it takes at least 15 minutes per run to check the solution (I know, I know, I should make the check alot quicker, but I am doing about 100 other things at the same time, so the runtime is not a big issue for me, other than delaying my posts here.)

Comment: @sanzo213 Okay, ffill method does not work, which is unfortunate. I am guessing this is due to the way pandas formats the pivot. From my understanding it actually holds multiple separate 2d dataframes and then stitches them together to create the pivot.

Comment: @sammywemmy I have tested out reset_index() and confirmed it is working. Thank you very much for the answer.
For anyone interested I had a bit of a look through various methods and found that the following works:
tempTable = tempTable.reset_index() # - Exec Time = 0.004787600017152727
tempTable = tempTable.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index() # - Exec Time = 0.005461400025524199
As expected the execution time is shorter when not including the '.rename_axis(None, axis=1)' section. Not sure how this scales as my pivot is actually fairly small (as you might guess based on the exec time).